# How to have 5 or 6 access points in this lighting circuit?

Tags: wiring, lighting

In the diagram below, if I wanted to have access from only 3 different points, what changes would I need to make? In the diagram I have 4 access points.

What if I wanted 5 or 6 access points?

[image]
[Image Source](https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/lighting-circuits-connections-interior-electrical-installations)

In the example below (taking into account only the circuit in blue), each point has access to three lamps. If I wanted to add a new lamp, could I simply do what's in the red circuit? Is there a limit to how many access points I can have?

[image]

In the circuit below if I only had the line diagram (a) and the numbers 1 and 2 didn't appear, how would I know which simple switch would power up its correspondent luminaire point?

[image]

Edit:

Control of one luminaire point from 5 multiple locations:

[image]

Control of one luminaire point from 3 multiple locations:

[image]

Edit 2:

Two more luminares points (lights)

[image]

edit 3:

[image]

Comment: 1. What is an "access point" in a lighting circuit? Do you mean switches or maybe "control point"? 2. Are you asking how to switch one lamp with many switches?

Comment: @Transistor 1. Connection of one or more luminaire points (Lights); 2. One of the questions is that yes

Comment: It looks like your first illustration has been taken from https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/lighting-circuits-connections-interior-electrical-installations. Site policy is that you must credit the work of others by, at least, providing the author's name or a link to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For control of one luminaire point from multiple locations you need some of the switches to be "intermediate" type.

[image]

*Figure 1. Switch 1 and 3 are 2-way switches. Switch 2 is an intermediate switch. (The symbol is not a good one.) In one position the wires are connected straight through. In the other position the wires are crossed. Image source: [Light Wiring UK](https://www.lightwiring.co.uk/tag/intermediate-light-switch-wiring/).*

If you look at Figure 1 you can see that any switch can change the state of the light.

If you need more than two switches then all the extra switches must be intermediate switches.

Comment: Can you see my new edit? For control of one luminaire point from 5 multiple locations i just added a intermediate switches. For control of one luminaire point from 3 multiple locations i "deleted" a intermediate switch. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. It's all described on the site where you got the first image (and didn't give credit).

Comment: Added the source and a new edit with two more lights. If i wanted to add two more luminaire points all i have to do is what is shown in edit 2 right?

Comment: No. You need four wires for each intermediate switch. You won't be able to add one *after* the three-wire switch. You'll have to add it between the rest of the switches and the three-wire switch.

Comment: If there was no luminaire in any of the 4 wire switches, could i still add one after the three-wire switch?

Comment: Draw it out as I have done in Figure 1 and see how you would wire the switches. Then see where the current would flow when each switch is operated.